# Relation of Sage Vashist with Puskar of Rajastan

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, rig-veda

The RigVedic hymn RV.7.33 (11)  seems to state that Vishvedevah had given Puskar to the sage Vashist. 
1. Is it the same  present day Puskar located in Rajasthan?
 
2. Is there any memory associated with the sage Vashist exist at preset day Puskar? 
3. Do any other scripture mention about this?

Answer (score 3):

> उतासि मैत्रावरुणो वसिष्ठोर्वश्या बरह्मन मनसो.अधि जातः | दरप्सं सकन्नं
>   बरह्मणा दैव्येन विश्वे देवाः पुष्करे तवाददन्त || 
> स परकेत उभयस्य
>   परविद्वान सहस्रदान उत वा सदानः | यमेन ततं परिधिं वयिष्यन्नप्सरसः परि
>   जज्ञे वसिष्ठः || 
> सत्रे ह जाताविषिता नमोभिः कुम्भे रेतः सिषिचतुः समानम
>   | ततो ह मान उदियाय मध्यात ततो जातं रषिमाहुर्वसिष्ठम ||
>   - **ऋग्वेद 7/33/11-13**

**Translation in Hindi**

> अर्थात "हे वसिष्ठ, तुम मित्र और वरुण के पुत्र हो। हे ब्रह्मण, तुम
>   उर्वशी के मन से उत्पन्न हो। उस समय मित्र और वरुण का वीर्य स्खलन हुआ
>   था। विश्वादेवगन ने दैव्य स्तोत्र द्वारा पुष्कर के बीच तुम्हें धारण
>   किया था। यज्ञ में दीक्षित मित्र और वरुण ने स्तुति द्वारा प्रार्थित हो
>   कर कुंभ के बीच एकसाथ ही रेत (वीर्य) स्खलन किया था। अनंतर मान
>   (अगस्त्य)उत्पन्न हुए। लोग कहते हंस कि ऋषि वसिष्ठ उसी कुंभ से जन्मे
>   थे."

**Translation in English**

> 11 Born of their love for Urvasi, Vasiṣṭha thou, priest, art son of
>   Varuṇa and Mitra; And as a fallen drop, in heavenly fervour, all the
>   Gods laid thee on a lotus-blossorn. 12 He thinker, knower both of
>   earth and heaven, endowed with many a gift, bestowing thousands,
>   Destined to wear the vesture spun by Yama, sprang from the Apsaras to
>   life, Vasiṣṭha. 13 Born at the sacrifice, urged by adorations, both
>   with a common flow bedewed the pitcher. Then from the midst thereof
>   there rose up Māna, and thence they say was born the sage Vasiṣṭha.

If you analyze the three translations you will conclude that in English translation there is no mention of word '***Pushkar***' whereas in Hindi & Sanskrit it is there though in Hindi it says that 'Vishwadevgana possessed you with help of godly stotra, in between/middle of Pushkar'.

So your assumption *"seems to state that Vishvedevah had given Puskar to the sage Vashist"* doesn't seem to be appropriate here.

Refer [1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07033.htm), [2](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9704DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT145&lpg=PT145&dq=%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE+%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B&source=bl&ots=0_G33QALzD&sig=2jUbqjXh-Q2aXk5OHfjsSckvrzs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKsN-mgZvXAhWJz4MKHTkkAS4Q6AEIODAG#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B&f=false)

Comment: What are references 2& 3   , and how they are related to answer ?  Especially no. 3. Also instead of giving numbers to the sources. Try to write the name of the book or site & the sources should preferably from authentic scriptures only.

Comment: @just_Do_It   The reference to two or more translation has no authority to change the real meaning of the original text of RigVeda. A simple knowledge of Sanskrit would give a literal meaning of -"Vishva Devah Puskare tva dadant" - as - "Vishva Devah had given flower in your hand".

Comment: @SwiftPushkar no 2 & 3 were for translations, wonder why do we always rely on english translations, done by some englishman who neither knows hindi nor knows sanskrit?

Comment: -1 The links you have provided in answer are demeaning and totally disrespecting Vedic gods and goddesses. There are several Hindi translation  available of Rig-Veda by Indian authors  on net. There is no need to choose this specific translation , as it  doesn't mentioning the name of the translator.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar so you mean to say english translations do not demean Vedic gods but hindi translations do? Well that is really a strange analysis indeed. Where is this written in Vedas? Any scriptures for that? If you refer the english translation above that too from a source you accept, then why the word Pushkar is missing from the translation? Your thoughts?

Comment: The whole point of discussion is of the author of this translation.. Besides the translation is from a site which is a anti Hinduism site and totally refuting vedas and demeaning them. Did you got the point?

Comment: So I think the source is invalid in this case as the translation is done by anti-Vedic and anti Hinduism site.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Got your point, thanks for that. Will keep that in mind from now on, but you didn't answer the question: why the word Pushkar is missing from the english translation?

Comment: I am retracting my downvote since you deleted the source. Thank you :)